# Why image size changes after import

Tags: python

There is a folder with 65 images. When i import(read in spyder) one by one(by first below code) images, the size of each image is (168, 192) which is according to data sheet. But when i import all these images together as a list with 65 members(by second below code) the size of each image(each member of list which it's name is image_list) changes to (192,168). Can anyone explain the reason of this change?

```
from PIL import Image

def read_img():
    im = Image.open("E:\\Face Recognition Projet\\CroppedYale\\yaleB01\\yaleB01_P00A-060E-20.pgm")
    im.show()    # Show pictures
    print(im.size)   # Output image size

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_img()     # Call read_img()




import numpy as np    
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('E:\\Face Recognition Projet\\CroppedYale\\yaleB02\\*.pgm'): #assuming gif
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet you have, whatever it is, may be listing sizes as height x width; PIL sizes are width x height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So can i say it is not important?